# How do I create an invisible character?

Tags: spacing, macros

I cannot remember how to create an invisible character in LaTeX, i.e. I want to put a space that has the width of a particular character, say `M'. I know there is a command for this, and this is a really dumb question, but my Google-fu has failed me.

Comment: Could you mark the answer that answers your question best as solution, please?

Answer (score 403):

You already found the answer, but let me expand a bit. There are three phantom commands. They each take a single argument.

1. `\hphantom` (**h**orizontal **phantom**) inserts an empty box that has zero height, zero depth, but the width of its argument.
2. `\vphantom` (**v**ertical **phantom**) inserts an empty box that has the height and depth of the argument, but zero width.
3. `\phantom` inserts an empty box with the same dimensions (horizontal as well as vertical) as the argument.

Comment: Why is there height, width and depth? 3D in typesetting?

Comment: Height is the length above the baseline, depth is the length below. So a character such as "X" will have a height but zero depth, and "g" has (a smaller) height as well as depth.

Comment: @Kit: You might also want to see the illustration in the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151584/25077

Comment: Also [Alexander R. Perlis' article in TUGboat, Volume 22 (2001), No. 4, p.350ff.](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf), might be of interest (especially the illustrations).

Comment: For 3D typesetting you need [iTeX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKaI78K_rgA).

Comment: Just an additional comment: The phantom commands can lead to some unexpected behavior, which can for example lead to additional blank lines as explained in egreg's answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216204/hphantom-in-tabulary-produces-extra-vertical-space-instead-of-horizontal) question.

Comment: @StackJack That's a great point. It can be useful to use `\leavevmode` or `\quitvmode` before using the various phantom commands when in vertical mode.

Comment: It may be useful to mention that in a math environment, the typesetter may wish to write `\mathbin{\phantom{%character%}}` in order to mimic the whitespace some operators are padded with in math mode.

Comment: Also, check this listing of different spacing commands: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/6468.

Comment: It seems that `\hphantom{}` an be used to create zero-width, non-printing content if TeX insists on having content but you don't want anything there (e.g. a bare `\paragraph{Foo}` where the next "real" content is unrelated).

Answer (score 78):

Ok, this has already been answered so I just want to contribute with the usage of the `\phantom` command.

```
\begin{document}
    This text will be visible. \\
    \phantom{This text will be invisible} \\
    \fbox{\phantom{This text will be invisible too, but a box will be printed arround it.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output.]

Answer (score 40):

OK, I finally found it.  The command is `\phantom`.