# nomencl: left alignment for description text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nomenclature

Does anyone know how to left align the description text of abbrevations in a nomencl list of abbrevations. For example: I would like to left align the text "Kategorien- und
Variablebezeichnungen" or "absolute Häufigkeit" in the following example. At the moment this text is justified. Thanks to all!

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,%
headings=small,%
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\let\abk\nomenclature                           
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}  
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}           
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}               
\RequirePackage{ifthen}                         
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\medskip\item[\textbf{Statistik}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{K}}{\medskip\item[\textbf{Notationskonventionen}]}}}
\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\setlength{\columnsep}{5pc}\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature[3.2cm]

\abk[S]{n}{Stichprobengröße}
\abk[S]{H\textsubscript{n}}{absolute Häufigkeit}
\abk[K]{\frqq\dots\flqq}{Kategorien- und Variablebezeichnungen}
\abk[K]{\textit{Kursivdruck}}{Objektsprache}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I don't completely understand you requirement; can you please explain a little more in detail what you mean with "I would like to left align the text "Kategorien- und Variablebezeichnungen" or "absolute Häufigkeit" in the following example"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for ragged right justification of the nomenclature. If so, try adding the [ragged2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package to the preamble, and putting the `\printnomenclature` in a group with `\RaggedRight`. Before (from your MWE):

[image]

after, adding

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

and changing to

```
{\RaggedRight
\printnomenclature[3.2cm]
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi mike! that's what i was looking for. thanks a lot! In addition, do you have any idea how to delete the dots after an subheading? In the example after "Statistik".

Comment: The nomgroups are also typeset as list items, so they're subject to the `\nomlabel` and other commands used to typeset the symbols and descriptions. The first header would have the dots, too, if could would fit in the 3.2cm allotted for the item width. Either drop the `\nomlabel` re-definition, decrease the 3.2cm to below the width of the word "Statistik", or add more words to "Statistik" to make its label longer than 3.2cm.

Comment: with the following code, which i got from an user in an other forum, it works great:    \medskip{\let\dotfill\relax\item[\textbf{Statistik}]}

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the problem with the dots behind "Statistik" one can insert a phantom text. An example could be:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\medskip\item[\textbf{Statistik \hphantom{Statistik}}]}{
```

Source: [How do I create an invisible character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-do-i-create-an-invisible-character)