# add white space to manually indent line

Tags: spacing, indentation

I'm trying to add space to a line so that it lines up with the text above it which is bulletpointed. If I add \indent to the second line it indents the above line too so that it is all shifted over.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\indent $\bullet$ This is the first line 
\\ This is the second line

\end{document}
```

I want the "This"'s to line up. I've tried adding \ to the line but it doesn't work at the start of the line.

Comment: Please give us a *complete* (mock-up) document illustrating your intent.

Comment: Please see the amended question

Comment: Doesn't the `{itemize}` environment fulfil your needs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to reinvent something.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is the first line \\ %line with dot
          This is the second line   %line without dot 
    \item Next line with dot
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: Just the first two lines would be closer to each other. I suggest `\item One \item[] Two \item Three`.

Answer (score 61):

For those who would like to know how to achieve space at the beginning of any line:

Tex prevents that, it has to have breakable text in front of white space. `\-` is the key for breakable, therefore `\-\ Text` works.

Comment: How would this work for adding more than one space?

Comment: With `\-\hspace{2cm}` or any other spacing operator - including `\-\pseudo{The space this would have used is left blank}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def{\b}{\thinspace} % \b gives on unit spacing.
\begin{document}
This is what is wri \b \b tten. This is what is writ \b ten. This \b \b \b is what is written.
\end{document}
 Here is the answer.
 
\noindent I do not want to answer.\\
\indent\hspace{2cm}I do not want to answer.\\
\indent\hspace{5cm}I do not want to
 answer. \\

\end{document}
```

Better to define once own term like `def{\b} {\thinspace} def{\c}{\hspace{1cm}}` This may work. When I entered the text it added single `\` which is command beginning. That was error.

Please enter your text so that I can compile and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an invisible character:

```
\texttt{if (true)\\
\hphantom{~~~~}do();}
```

[image]

But it doesn't work this way with an indented paragraph:

```
\indent $\bullet$ This is the first line \\
\hphantom{$\bullet$} This is the second line\\
This is the third line
```

[image]

see [How do I create an invisible character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-do-i-create-an-invisible-character)