# Fixed text line height?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I have two minipages and the problem that the height of a text line depends on the characters I am using. How can I always have the same height for a text line in a minipage?

I have used Tikz to demonstrate my problem. As you can see the baselines of each row are not aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, rectangle, red, draw, minimum width=0.5cm](A) {%
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}%
x\\
x%
\end{minipage}};

\node[inner sep=0, rectangle, blue, draw, minimum width=0.5cm, right=0.1cm of A.north east, anchor=north west](B) {%
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}%
M\\
M%
\end{minipage}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `minipage`s or `tikz` pictures?

Comment: minipage are centred by default so baselines are not aligned, use `\begin{minipage}[t]` so they align on the baseline of the top row

Comment: @Sigur: What do you mean? I am using minipages in tikz nodes.

Comment: But why to use `minipage` inside a `node` since a `node` works like a `minipage` by itself?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This doesn't solve my problem. The problem is that character "x" has a smaller height than character "M" so that Latex reserved less space for these text lines

Comment: try adding `\strut` to all lines.

Comment: @Sigur: I need line breaks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Cool, this solved my problem but how can I set it for a whole minipage at once? (I have a lot of text and it would be quite painful to add \strut before every line).

Comment: as long as what is contained in the minipage is entered as a "paragraph", and the type size has an appropriate baseline, you only need two struts -- one at the beginning and one at the end.  you could probably even create a command that would manage that for you.

Comment: @user4811 if [t] doesn't solve your problem you haven't described the problem well:-) if the tikz frame is only for debugging then the two minipages would align on the baselines and the line box holding them would be big enough for both so no extra space would need to be allocated. If you do want a visible frame then you need a strut as barbara said, or use a tabular p column (which adds the struts implictitly)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that was the problem. I guess that OP want to put it inside a node.

Comment: I guess that http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124114/14757 can help you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: \strut does the trick. I have adapted my example to show you what I wanted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Feel free to make an answer out of your comments. I will then delete the solution in my question.

Comment: @user4811 does your real example have the visible frame, or do you just need the baselines aligned?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I just need the baselines aligned. My real Code is a protocol description.

Comment: so you don't need the struts then:-) just remove all the tikz and  put two minipage[t] side by side and they will align on baselines naturally (I'll add that to my answer)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't need the visible frame but I do need Tikz to draw the rest of the protocol (arrows etc.).

Comment: Did you read this answer: [Tikz labels are shifted dependent on the letters size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151867/14500)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as long as what is contained in the minipage is entered as a "paragraph",
and the type size has an appropriate baseline, two struts, one at the beginning
and one at the end would guarantee uniform treatment of the content.
strictly speaking, the strut at the bottom is not usually necessary, but if the
content is boxed, and you have multiple such boxes (such as in a flow chart),
this will look better if the last line in one of the boxes has no descenders.

as noted in various comments, the option `[t]` is needed if the (baseline of the) top
lines are to be the "hook" for positioning the boxes.

you could probably even create a command that would manage all the details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, rectangle, red, draw, minimum width=0.5cm](A) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
\strut x\\
x\\
x\\
\strut x%
\end{minipage}};

\node[inner sep=0, rectangle, blue, draw, minimum width=0.5cm, right=0.1cm of A.north east, anchor=north west](B) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
\strut M\\
M\\
M\\
\strut M%
\end{minipage}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary to make the two boxes have the same height to align on the baselines, you just need to align on baselines rather than vertically centering the box.

If you want to make a visible frame around the box, then it is convenient to ensure they have the same height with a `\strut` , as shown in the second example.

If you don't need the visible tikz frames it is much easier, just place the `minipage` side by side, aligned on their top baseline as shown in the third example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor = base west, inner sep=0, rectangle, red, draw, minimum width=0.5cm](A) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
x\\
x%
\end{minipage}};

\node[anchor = base west, inner sep=0, rectangle, blue, draw, minimum width=0.5cm, base right=0.1cm of A.base east, ](B) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
M\\
M%
\end{minipage}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor = base west, inner sep=0, rectangle, red, draw, minimum width=0.5cm](A) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
\strut x\\
x%
\end{minipage}};

\node[anchor = base west, inner sep=0, rectangle, blue, draw, minimum width=0.5cm, base right=0.1cm of A.base east, ](B) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
\strut M\\
M%
\end{minipage}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
x\\
x
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
M\\
M
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use `minipage` inside a `node` you can insert a vertical rule with zero width on first line of both mini pages.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
x\rule{0pt}{1cm} \\  %% choose the height
x
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\rule{0pt}{1cm}M \\  %% choose the height
M
\end{minipage}
```

I used a colored rule with `0.4pt` on the image below just to show the result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if, instead of "x", one of these boxes contains "y", you'll have a problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I can not see a problem. See the edited post. I'm supposing that OP wants to align the base line of the first line.

Comment: you need [t] as discussed in comments otherwise the position of the baselines in the minipage is not available