# Fixed vertical spacing between items

Tags: enumerate, itemize, baseline, vertical-spacing

Is there a way to ensure that the vertical spacing between every item (line) in a list is exactly the same? I tried specifying the "itemsep", but the resulting spacing still depends on what characters are written in the respective line. See below an example, where the separation between bullets 1 and 2 is smaller than the rest, because line 1 has no character like "p" or "y" or "," that go below the baseline:

[image: Separation between items in a list, superimposed with a regular vertical grid (in red)]

Below the example code:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Vendor
\item Repositories
\item Measurements,
\item Cylinders
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple hack with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet\vphantom{y}]
\item Vendor
\item Repositories
\item Measurements,
\item Cylinders
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround inspired by: [Fixed text line height?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152913/fixed-text-line-height)

Below the solution:

```
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-0.8mm]{0pt}{3.5mm}}%custom strut
\begin{itemize}
\item \mystrut Vendor
\item \mystrut Repositories
\item \mystrut Measurements,
\item \mystrut Cylinders
\end{itemize}
```

But I had to play around with the strut height and position for a while until being able to fix it. Does anyone know a better way of doing this universally without trial and error?