# Format single node in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

Is it possible to format a single node in tikzcd? In the below MWE, I would like the `\dots` cell to not have an ellipse.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse}}]
        0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & \dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & n
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tikzcd` is in fact only an improvement of `matrix` in Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse}}]
        0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & n
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, to have nice arrows, I think some improvements are needed. Here are some proposals to do so:

1. Use phantom (as suggested by marmot in the comments)

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
       \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse}}]
           0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots\vphantom{1} \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & n
       \end{tikzcd}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   We can even improve this approach more by using `\cdots`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
       \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse}}]
           0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\cdots\vphantom{1} \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & n
       \end{tikzcd}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Use option `anchor=center`

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
       \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse,anchor=center}}]
           0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & n
       \end{tikzcd}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Moreover, to make the height of the nodes consistent, you may need `minimum height` option (here I apply it to the `anchor=center` code – you can apply this to any code above):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse,anchor=center,minimum height=2em}}]
        0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & n
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had.

Comment: @DavidPoxon No problems :) You're welcome.

Comment: @marmot Thanks for pointing that out :) I added your proposal and two more to my answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `\vphantom{1}` do here?

Comment: @DavidPoxon `\phantom{1}` gives an invisible `1`; `\hphantom{1}` gives a space which is as wide as a `1`, and `\vphantom{1}` gives a vertical space which is as high as a `1`. Read more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4523/156344