# New shape format of a singe node in tikzcd (rewrite cells option)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, commutative-diagrams

I need your help.

How to get a new custom shape of a node in a tikzcd diagramm which uses option `cells={nodes={ellipse}}`?

I've tried to use a trick with `|[cells={nodes={draw=red, rectangular}}]|`, but in vain.

MWE is from [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484743/format-single-node-in-tikzcd).

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse,anchor=center,minimum height=2em}}]
            0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & |[cells={nodes={draw=red, rectangular}}]|n
            \end{tikzcd}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Desired effect:

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse,anchor=center,minimum height=2em}}]
            0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & 
   |[shape=rectangle]|n
  \end{tikzcd}  \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse,anchor=center,minimum height=2em}}]
            0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & 
   |[shape=rectangle]|n
  \end{tikzcd}` i.e. add `shape=rectangle`.

Answer (score 6):

You're overcomplicating a bit, you just need

```
|[draw=red, rectangle]|
```

in the cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse,anchor=center,minimum height=2em}}]
        0 \arrow[r] & 1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=none]|\dots \arrow[r] & n-1 \arrow[r] & |[draw=red, rectangle]|n
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Overcomplicating is almost everywhere in my life, unfortunatelly..

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko Don't worry about the difficulties. Think about how much I have with the LaTeX :-)

Comment: Thanks once again))