# Proper vertical alignment of text in tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes

Yuck. Presence/absence of descender characters seems to shift the baseline of my text. How do I align the text properly?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\h{0.55cm} 
\def\w{1.5cm}
\tikzset{
  myboxshape/.style={rectangle, outer sep=0, minimum width = \w, minimum height = \h, inner sep=0},
  mybox/.style={myboxshape, very thin, draw},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[]
{
 \node[mybox] {Vertical}; & \node[mybox] {grungy};  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `text depth=0.25ex`, say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I would define node's style in matrix option. For desired  vertical align I would in node's style define node anchor, text depth and text height:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\h{5.5mm}
\def\w{15mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, very thin, inner sep=0pt,
             minimum width=\w, minimum height=\h, 
             text height=2ex, text depth=0.75ex, anchor=base}, % <---
             column sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
             row sep=0pt
             ]
{
Vertical    &   grungy  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ah.... text height and depth are the things I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack: by adding an invisible character the **same height** as `V` and the **same depth** as `gy` but **zero width**. `\vphantom{Vgy}`

See: [How do I create an invisible character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4519/138900)

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\h{0.55cm} 
\def\w{1.5cm}
\tikzset{
  myboxshape/.style={rectangle, outer sep=0, minimum width = \w, minimum height = \h, inner sep=0},
  mybox/.style={myboxshape, very thin, draw},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[]
{
 \node[mybox] {\vphantom{gy}Vertical}; & \node[mybox] {grungy\vphantom{V}};  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g. adding `text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em` yields

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\h{0.55cm} 
\def\w{1.5cm}
\tikzset{
  myboxshape/.style={rectangle, outer sep=0, minimum width = \w, minimum height = \h, inner sep=0},
  mybox/.style={myboxshape, very thin, draw,text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
{
 \node[mybox] {Vertical}; & \node[mybox] {grungy};  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that there are many ways to simplify this. They include the use of `matrix of nodes`, i.e. you load the `matrix` library but do not really use it.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myboxshape/.style={rectangle, outer sep=0, 
    minimum width = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mydims/w}, 
    minimum height =  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mydims/h}, inner sep=0},
  mybox/.style={myboxshape, very thin, draw,text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em},
  mydims/.cd,h/.initial=0.55cm,w/.initial=1.5cm]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={mybox}]
{
 Vertical & grungy  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```